# How to read data from a repeated format of a large text file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file-io, format, text-files, repeat

I want to read data of average saturation (%) for water as shown below. This data is a partial form of a large file, however the average water saturation (%) REPEATS itself in the given format only.

```
Average Pressure 
   Total Pore Volume  psia      3884.9                                                                                              
   HC. Pore Volume    psia      3884.9                                                                                              
 Average P/Z 
   Total Pore Volume  psia      4457.8                                                                                              
   HC. Pore Volume    psia      4457.8                                                                                              
 Average Saturation %
   Oil                          84.911                                                                                              
   Gas                          .08873                                                                                              
   Water                        15.000                                                                                              
 Percentage Recovery 
   Stock Tank Oil               .02211                                                                                              
   STO as a % of Mobile Oil     .02891                                                                                              
   Total Gas                    .02034                                                                                              
   Water                        62e-12
```

I was trying to do it by using [readline.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20026-readline-m-v3-0-jun-2009) function, but unfortunately the position of average water saturation (%) data is not fixed by line number. The line number changes for similar kind of output file for different models.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
%# Reading Water Saturation (Sw) data from output (.OUT) file of reservoir model
    Sw_LineNo=[554,968,1120,1272,1424,1576,1728,1880,2032,2184,2336,2488,2640,2792,2944,3096,3248,3400,3552,3704,3856]; % This column vector contains the line numbers of the .out file with Sw values for year 1 till 20

    for i=1:size(Sw_LineNo,2)
    read_value=readline('ReservoirModel_ExplorWell_CMGBuilder.out',Sw_LineNo(i)); % read_value stores values in form of string
    Swav_Data_E_W(i,j)=str2num(read_value(33:38)); % converts the required portion of string (Sw value) to number
    end
```

Now if my model (`ReservoirModel_ExplorWell_CMGBuilder.out`) changes, then the line numbers where the average saturation (%) for water lies in the text file also changes. Thus `Sw_LineNo` changes for different models, and I have large number of models.

Please suggest correct way to read all the average saturation (%) for water data.

Comment: Try searching for the string "Average Saturation" first and then the string "Water" instead of putting in all the line numbers. Repeat this procedure until the end of file. This should work for any output file as long as the order of these two strings remains constant.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the function and its usage in the respect of this problem?

Comment: You can proceed exactly like in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561843/how-to-read-data-in-chunks-from-notepad-file-in-matlab/3562153#3562153)

Comment: Jonas: Thanks, it worked. However in previous problem we were able to convert the string to number, but here if I do that then I get an empty [] number. So I converted the string to a character and did something very crude to get the saturation values. Please see my answer below. If you have some suggestion to extract the number out of that string, then please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%# Reading Average Water Saturation (Savw) data from output (.OUT) file of reservoir model
    fid = fopen('ReservoirModel_CMGBuilder.out'); % open the file

    dotOUT_fileContents = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n'); % read it into one big array, row by row
    dotOUT_fileContents = dotOUT_fileContents{1};
    fclose(fid); %# don't forget to close the file again

    %# find rows containing 'Average Saturation %'
    Swav_Starts = strmatch('Average Saturation %',dotOUT_fileContents); % Swav_Starts contains the line numbers wherever 'Average Saturation %' is found
    nSwav = length(Swav_Starts); % total no. of Swav values will be equal to the total no. of 'Average Saturation %' read from the .out file

    %# loop through the file and read the numeric data
    for w = 1:nSwav 
        %# read lines containing numbers
        tmp_str = dotOUT_fileContents(Swav_Starts(w)+3); % stores the content of the 3rd row from the row containing 'Average Saturation %' in form of string
        tmp_str = tmp_str{:}; % store the content of the string which contains Swav, as well, in form of a character
        %# assign output
        Swav_yearly(w,j) = str2num(tmp_str(30:35)); % convert the part of the character containing Swav into number
    end
```

Now the `tmp_str = dotOUT_fileContents(Swav_Starts(w)+3);` produces the following string:

```
Water                        15.000
```

If I try to convert it to number using str2num, then I get an empty matrix. So I pick the characters of this string containing the saturation value (here `15.000`) and then changing this character to number as follow, giving the value of the average water saturation:

```
str2num(tmp_str(30:35))
```

Please advice if someone has any method to extract number out of the string without picking the characters as I have done.